# How to create a new folder in Camera roll?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air

Is it possible to create a new folder in the Android gallery (Camera Roll) to save my created images in the Air mobile application?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is create a new folder on the external storage, put your images in it and it will show up in Gallery.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. But if I save images in applicationStorageDirectory, they will not show up in Gallery.

Comment: Don't use applicationStorageDirectory :)